# Multithreading on object methods in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to implement multi threading with oops

```
class test:
    def printer(self):
        for ctr in range(1000000):
            print("hello")

    def printHi(self):
        for ctr in range(1000000):
            print("hi")
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test1 = test()

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1.printHi, args=(10,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=test1.printer, args=(10,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    print("Done!")
```

But the test1.printHi is expecting me to pass self

```
Exception in thread Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

TypeError: printHi() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were givenTypeError: 
printer() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Done!
```

After passing self it is not being multi threaded any more It

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1.printHi())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=test1.printer())
t1.start()
print("next")
t2.start()
```

Its first printing all hi and then hello at last next is getting printed but when I implement them like functions its working properly they are getting printed at once combined. Whats the right way to implement it properly such that both threads runs simultaneously...

Comment: You cannot have two loops working simultaneously in python, the GIL will only allow one thread to execute code, the other will have to wait.

Comment: If you want to execute both loops at the same time then you should use multiprocessing, which has limitations in terms of memory.

Comment: As pointed out by jiri, you must use sleep so the GIL will be transferred if you aim to use threading.

Comment: Threading in python only improves performance if your task is waiting on external resources (like reading from disk or internet) where python threads will release the GIL while waiting, so other threads can run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be passing an extra 10 to the methods; try:

```
class test:
    def printer(self):
        for ctr in range(10):
            print("hello")
            time.sleep(1)

    def printHi(self):
        for ctr in range(10):
            print("hi")
            time.sleep(1)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test1 = test()

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1.printHi, args=())
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=test1.printer, args=())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    print("Done!")
```

Or, if you want to keep the parameter, the functions need to accept it:

```
class test:
    def printer(self, n):
        for ctr in range(10):
            print("hello", n)
            time.sleep(1)

    def printHi(self, n):
        for ctr in range(10):
            print("hi", n)
            time.sleep(1)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test1 = test()

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1.printHi, args=(10,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=test1.printer, args=(10,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: What's the new error message?

Comment: object.methodname this is giving me a error that it need self

Comment: object.methodname() is fixing the error but its misbehaving hi and hello are not getting printed at once

Comment: None of the errors you've posted mention needing `self`...

Comment: `object.methodname` will automatically supply `self`, so that's probably not the problem...

Comment: BTW, you may want to add a `time.sleep(1)` in the two loops; otherwise it may finish the first thread before starting the second even when it's working correctly

Comment: that why I gave a very large range in for loop to avoid sleep()

Comment: A large range may not necessarily trigger a thread switch, while a `sleep` will